# How do you map Korean Hanja sounds to Japanese Kanji sounds?

Tags: pronunciation, kanji

I think they’re related somehow.

Comment: Do you know keywords like [Middle Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Chinese) or [Sino-Xenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Xenic_pronunciations)? Most modern reflections of Chinese character reading in Asian languages are thought to be promulgated from a specific dialect in a specific period.

Comment: And I actually think it should be sent to Linguistics SE regardless of how the title looks like.

Comment: @broccolifacemask I know. That would the reason behind the similarities. I was just explicitly writing down the mappings as it was helpful for me to learn Japanese. Given that, this is pretty much like any other Q&As here on Japanese language SE except that it’s not intended for English speakers. It’s fine by me to migrate this to Linguistics SE, but I’m just not sure which SE it fits best on.

Answer (score 1):

For most Japanese Kanji, their *on’yomi* sounds can easily be deduced from the sounds of the corresponding Korean Hanja in a consistent and expectable manner. The speakers of the Korean language, who have a decent Hanja vocabulary, would notice that these *rules* exist and take advantage of them to figure out the sounds of Japanese Kanji words.

## How to convert Korean Hanja sounds to Japanese Kanji sounds

### Mapping the *initial consonants* of Hanja sounds

- “ㄱ<sub>g/k</sub>/ㄲ<sub>kk</sub>/ㅋ<sub>k</sub>/ㅎ<sub>h</sub>” → “k”

  - 家 — 가<sub>ka</sub> → か<sub>ka</sub>
  - 快 — 쾌<sub>kwe</sub> → かい<sub>kai</sub>
  - 夏 — 하<sub>ha</sub> → か<sub>ka</sub>
- “ㄴ<sub>n</sub>” → “n/d”

  - 內 — 내<sub>ne/de</sub> → ない<sub>nai</sub>
  - 南 — 남<sub>nam/dam</sub> → なん<sub>nan</sub>
  - 努 — 노<sub>no/do</sub> → ど<sub>do</sub>
- “ㄷ<sub>d/t</sub>/ㅌ<sub>t</sub>” → “t/d”

  - 多 — 다<sub>da/ta</sub> → た<sub>ta</sub>
  - 達 — 달<sub>dal/tal</sub> → たつ<sub>tatsu</sub>
  - 誕 — 탄<sub>tan</sub> → たん<sub>tan</sub>
  - 代 — 대<sub>de/te</sub> → だい<sub>dai</sub>
- “ㄹ<sub>r</sub>” → “r”

  - 樂 — 락<sub>rak</sub> → らく<sub>raku</sub>
  - 來 — 래<sub>re</sub> → らい<sub>rai</sub>
  - 論 — 론<sub>ron</sub> → ろん<sub>ron</sub>
- “ㅁ<sub>m/b</sub>” → “m”

  - 滿 — 만<sub>man/ban</sub> → まん<sub>man</sub>
  - 文 — 문<sub>mun/bun</sub> → もん<sub>mon</sub>
  - 密 — 밀<sub>mil/bil</sub> → みつ<sub>mitsu</sub>
- “ㅂ<sub>b/p</sub>/ㅍ<sub>p</sub>” → “h”

  - 博 — 박<sub>bak/pak</sub> → はく<sub>haku</sub>
  - 秘 — 비<sub>pi</sub> → ひ<sub>hi</sub>
  - 派 — 파<sub>pa</sub> → は<sub>ha</sub>
  - 避 — 피<sub>pi</sub> → ひ<sub>hi</sub>
- “ㅅ<sub>s</sub>/ㅈ<sub>dz/ch</sub>/ㅊ<sub>ch</sub>/ㅉ<sub>jj</sub>” → “s/z/t”

  - 思 — 사<sub>sa</sub> → し<sub>si</sub>
  - 財 — 재<sub>dze/che</sub> → さい<sub>sai</sub>/ざい<sub>zai</sub>
  - 差 — 차<sub>cha</sub> → さ<sub>sa</sub>
- “ㅇ<sub>∅</sub>” → “k/g/∅”

  - 完 — 완<sub>wan</sub> → かん<sub>kan</sub>
  - 癌 — 암<sub>am</sub> → がん<sub>gan</sub>
  - 眼 — 안<sub>an</sub> → がん<sub>gan</sub>
  - 願 — 원<sub>won</sub> → がん<sub>gan</sub>
  - 安 — 안<sub>an</sub> → あん<sub>an</sub>
  - 溫 — 온<sub>on</sub> → おん<sub>on</sub>
  - 位 — 위<sub>wi</sub> → い<sub>i</sub>

### Mapping the *vowels* of Hanja sounds

- “ㅏ<sub>a</sub>/ㅘ<sub>wa</sub>” → “ぁ<sub>a</sub>”

  - 家 — 가<sub>ga/ka</sub> → か<sub>ka</sub>
  - 間 — 간<sub>gan/kan</sub> → かん<sub>kan</sub>
  - 樂 — 락<sub>rak</sub> → らく<sub>raku</sub>
  - 単 — 단<sub>dan/tan</sub> → たん<sub>tan</sub>
  - 癌 — 암<sub>am</sub> → がん<sub>gan</sub>
  - 眼 — 안<sub>an</sub> → がん<sub>gan</sub>
  - 完 — 완<sub>wan</sub> → かん<sub>kan</sub>
  - 館 — 관<sub>gwan/kwan</sub> → かん<sub>kan</sub>
- “ㅑ<sub>ya</sub>” → “ゃ<sub>ya</sub>”

  - 夜 — 야<sub>ya</sub> → や<sub>ya</sub>
  - 約 — 약<sub>yak</sub> → やく<sub>yaku</sub>
  - 略 — 략<sub>ryak</sub> → りゃく<sub>ryaku</sub>
- ㅓ<sub>ʌ̹</sub> → ぇ<sub>e</sub>/ぉ<sub>o</sub>/ょ<sub>yo</sub>/ゃ<sub>ya</sub>

  - 件 — 건<sub>gʌ̹n/kʌ̹n</sub> → けん<sub>ken</sub>
  - 見 — 견<sub>gyʌ̹n/kyʌ̹n</sub> → けん<sub>ken</sub>
  - 驗 — 험<sub>hʌ̹m</sub> → けん<sub>ken</sub>
  - 憶 — 억<sub>ʌ̹k</sub> → おく<sub>oku</sub>
  - 德 — 덕<sub>dʌ̹k/tʌ̹k</sub> → とく<sub>toku</sub>
  - 抑 — 억<sub>ʌ̹k</sub> → よく<sub>yoku</sub>
  - 石 — 석<sub>sʌ̹k</sub> → せき<sub>seki</sub>/しゃく<sub>syaku</sub>/こく<sub>koku</sub>
- ㅕ → yo/ya/e/i

  - 歷
  - 逆
  - 力
- ㅝ

  - 權 — 권<sub>gwon/kwon</sub> → けん<sub>ken</sub>

……(to be written)……

### Mapping the *final consonants* of Hanja sounds

- “ᆨ<sub>k/g</sub>” → “く<sub>ku</sub>/き<sub>ki</sub>”
- “ᆫ<sub>n</sub>/ᆷ<sub>m</sub>” → “ん<sub>n</sub>”
- “ᆯ<sub>l</sub>” → “つ<sub>tsu</sub>”
- “ᆸ<sub>p</sub>/ᆼ<sub>ng</sub>” → “う<sub>u</sub>”

……(to be written)……